# How to find Bluetooth devices that aren't on discoverable mode?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluecove

We're trying to develop an app that's going to mark students presence. In order to do this we're using bluecove to detect the students phone but the phones are only discoverable for 120s.

We've developed an Android app that keeps it going forever, which works but uses too much resources. Does anyone know a better way to do this? Currently we're trying to detect phones that have once being paired and are not discoverable, Bluetooth is on. Our last option is to just mark the presence at the beginning and end of class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to detect a Bluetooth device which is not discover-able. Therefore, you can have an app that detects the phone IDs and bind each ID to a pupil upon discovery and from your register from that. This wont work unless their phone is set to discover-able. So either ask them to turn it on or just record manually.